# Did the Romans 'tip' for good service?

Tags: idiom, word-request, history, roman-culture

I need to refer in Latin to the modern practice of 'tipping' in return for good service. I am well aware of words and phrases for 'reward', which are essentially correct for my purpose, but I should like, if possible, something both specific and authentically classical, and wonder if there is any reference to such a practice?

Comment: In Spanish, "tip" is "propina," but *propino/propinatio* in Latin seems to refer only to the act of drinking another's health.

Comment: @brianpck Rather like the French _pourboire_, then!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that [*corollarium*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=corollarium&la=la#lexicon) was used in this sense.  Lewis and Short describe the original meaning as "money paid for a garland of flowers", but elsewhere it is described more like money put in a garland "and so a free gift" (editor's note on Lucilius, *Satires*, 12.464).

However, here Seneca uses it in the sense of tipping for services rendered:

> *Sordidissimorum quoque artificiorum institoribus supra constitutum
>   aliquid adiecimus, si nobis illorum opera enixior visa est; et
>   gubernatori et opifici vilissimae mercis et in diem locanti manus suas
>   **corollarium** adspersimus.*
>
> If the hawkers of even the meanest forms of service seem to us to have
>   put forth unusual effort, we give them something besides what we have
>   agreed upon; we dispense **gratuities** to a pilot, to a man who works
>   with the commonest material, and to one who hires out his services by
>   the day.

*On Benefits*, 6.17, (trans. John W. Basore)

Answer (score 8):

It's often held that the practice of tipping began in England around the 16th century, but there's some difference of opinion on the subject. For example:

> There are a few versions for the origin of tipping. Hemenway (1993)
>   claims that tipping was known as far back as the Roman era and is
>   probably much older. Schein, Jablonski and Wohlfahrt (1984) assert
>   that tipping originated back in the days of feudal lords. When lords
>   met groups of beggars along their way, they tossed the beggars coins
>   in an attempt to buy a safe passage. It is arguable, however, if this
>   kind of payment should be considered tipping. Segrave (1998) suggests
>   that tipping may have begun in the late Middle Ages. (Ofer H. Azar,  "The
>   history of tipping", 2004)

David Hemenway makes the following claim:

> Popular belief holds that tip derives from eighteenth-century English
>   usage and stands for the words 'to insure promptness,' but tipping was
>   known as far back as the roman era and is probably much older. The
>   word tip itself may come from stipend, a bastardized version of the
>   Latin *stips* meaning gift. (Hemenway, Prices and Choices, 1977, p.77)

For this word *stips*, Lewis' *[An Elementary Latin Dictionary](https://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=1015594)* has the following:

> (*stips*) *stipis*, f — STIP-, a contribution in money, gift, donation,
>   alms contribution, dole. *ne quis stipem cogito*, lex ap. C.: *stipem
>   sustulimus*, i. e. begging: *stipem Apollini conferre*, L.: *stipis adice*
>   *causam*, O.: *suburbanum hortum exiguā colere stipe*, Cu.

Cicero used this word in *De Legibus*:

> Praeter Idaeae Matris famulos eosque iustis deiubus, ne quis **stipen**
>   cogito.

Which has been translated as "No one shall ask for contributions except the servants of the Idean Mother, and they only on the appointed days." In another part, he says:

> **Stipem** sustulimus, nisi eam quam ad paucos dies propriam, Id matris
>   excepimus, implet enim superstitione animos, et exhaurit domos.

I'm guessing that this word might be well-suited for your purposes. However, I think it still remains doubtful that its meaning is the same as that of tipping, i.e. as a gratuity for services rendered. As the following entry from *[A Compendious Dictionary of the Latin Tongue](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=6_IsAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA665&lpg=PA665&dq=%22stipem%20sustulimus%22&source=bl&ots=91CWJ8_mGk&sig=qHYDj5jnRqkEXgucTP0D4VLZWS0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0yqzy5qveAhVEi5AKHeNVD7YQ6AEwBnoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22stipem%20sustulimus%22&f=false)* shows, it was used in the sense of a gift or offering (often in a religious context), as well as for the begging of alms:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I first had in mind the word *mercedula*, which is used in this sense — though it's fairly rare — and I asked the question thinking that I might find something rather better. In two excellent replies I have found *stips* and *corollarium*, each quite unknown to me. *Gratias ago utrique.*

Since *stips* seems mainly (wholly?) used for religious gifts, it has less appeal than *corollarium*, which in Penelope's answer is also in fact paid among other examples for a maritime service and therefore quite apposite to the passage for translation, which was:

"It was an old fisherman who, with immense difficulty, at last rescued us . . . . .  What between tipping the man who had brought us home, and paying for the broken sculls . . . . . " *(Jerome K. Jerome, 'Three Men in a Boat')*.

Comment: So happy I could help in even a small way with a translation of _Three Men in a Boat_!